# Fade out edges in scroll view

Tags: ios, xcode, menu, fade

I just wanted to inquire if it would be possible to have a faded edge on Xcode. Basically i have a menu and i want to know if theres a way to make it so when i scroll up or down, the edges are faded a little to show scrolling is possible. I know android has this feature too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be what you are after?
http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/08/adding-fading-gradients-to-uitableview/